# EF: How to pass column name dynamically to where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am not before dev pc. i just started working with EF. so curious to know can we pass column name dynamically for where clause.

see a screen shot for searching grid.

[image]

i just compose a sample query. please tell me does it work?

```
public ActionResult Index(String ColumnName,String SearchText)
{

    private CustomersEntities db = new CustomersEntities();

    var customer = (from s in db.Customers
                    select new CustomerDTO
                    {
                    CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                    CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                    ContactName = s.ContactName,
                    ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
                    Address = s.Address
                    })
    .Where(s => s.Field<string>(ColumnName).ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper());

    return View(customer);

}
```

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422176/6188148

Comment: ok, what is the problem with your code? doesn't  compile? doesn't work as expected? don't  you like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11994614/6188148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index(string ColumnName, string SearchText)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");

    var strType = typeof(string);
    var ToUpperMeth = strType.GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == nameof(string.ToUpper) 
                                          && x.GetParameters().Count() == 0).Single();
    var ContainsMeth = strType.GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == nameof(string.Contains) 
                                          && x.GetParameters().Count() == 1).Single();

    var exprVal = Expression.Constant(SearchText);
    var toUpExprVal = Expression.Call(exprVal, ToUpperMeth);

    var exprProp = Expression.Property(arg, ColumnName);
    var toUpExpr = Expression.Call(exprProp, ToUpperMeth);
    var contExpr = Expression.Call(toUpExpr, ContainsMeth, toUpExprVal);

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(contExpr, arg);

    var customer = (from s in db.Customers
                    select new CustomerDTO
                    {
                        CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                        CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                        ContactName = s.ContactName,
                        ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
                        Address = s.Address
                    }).Where(predicate).ToList();

    return View(customer);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i have one request that can u please see this post and tell me why some one use AsEnumerable() when working with EF. see the code they use AsEnumerable() before select but why? i many time use EF select but never use AsEnumerable() before it. so tell me the reason for using there AsEnumerable(). https://stackoverflow.com/q/48723564/6188148

Comment: @Slava Thank you so so much! I don't even completely understand how this works but it works beautifully. Couln't ever come to a solution my self. I would pay you a coffe sir. Just send me a Binance ETH wallet adress.

Answer (score 2):

You can create something like this in repository (if you use it)

```
public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<CustomersEntities>().Where(predicate);
}
```

and then

```
var result = _repository.FindBy(y => y.CompanyName.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: thanks for reply but here you use column name `y => y.CompanyName.IndexOf` but i want to pass customer name as string.

Comment: Why do you want to pass customer name as string? It will be more safest to use really field with known type and intellisense

Comment: i have update my post code. please have a look for better understand.

Answer (score -1):

The basic pattern is to build up the query at runtime, selectively adding `Where` expressions before running the query and projecting the results into the DTO.

Like this:

```
        public IList<CustomerDTO> FindCustomers(String ColumnName, String SearchText)
        {

            var query = from s in db.Customers select s;

            if (ColumnName == "CompanyName")
            {
                query = query.Where(c => c.CompanyName == SearchText);
            }
            else if (ColumnName == "ContactName")
            {
                query = query.Where(c => c.ContactName == SearchText);
            }
            //. . .
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Column {ColumnName} not found or not supported for searching.");
            }

            var results = from c in query
                        select new CustomerDTO()
                        {
                            CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                            ContactName = c.ContactName,
                            ContactTitle = c.ContactTitle,
                            Address = c.Address
                        };

            return results;

        }
```

Comment: the things i am looking for not possible with ef?

Comment: You can do this dynamically with reflection and expressions, but what's the point?  Your Entities don't just change at runtime.

Comment: see my picture posted here. if my dropdown has 100 fields then i have to too many if..else. that may looks odd

Comment: 100 search fields _is_ odd, so the code should look odd.