# Entity Framework: Why people use .AsEnumerable() along with EF query

Tags: entity-framework

I have never yet used `.AsEnumerable()` in an EntityFramework query.

See the below example and tell me why they use `.AsEnumerable()` before `Select` ?

Could they not just use `Select` directly?

Please tell me the reason for the usage of `.AsEnumerable()` here in below query.

Why did they use `.ToArray()` instead of `.Tolist()` ?

```
private IEnumerable<AutoCompleteData> GetAutoCompleteData(string searchTerm)
{
    using (var context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
    {
        var results = context.Products
            .Include("ProductSubcategory")
            .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
                        && p.DiscontinuedDate == null)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(p => new AutoCompleteData
                                {
                                    Id = p.ProductID,
                                    Text = BuildAutoCompleteText(p)
                                })
            .ToArray();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `AsEnumerable` and `AsQueryable` is that the enumerable contains all information to create an enumerator. Once you've got the enumerator you can ask for the first element, and if there is one, you can get the next one.

The `Queryable` does not hold the information to create the enumerator. It holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Provider` knows which process must execute the `Expression` and which language this process uses. Quite often the other process is a database management system, and the language is SQL.

The result of a [Queryable.Select(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743(v=vs.110).aspx) is still an `IQueryable`, meaning that the query is not performed yet. The Select function only changed the `Expression`.

Only if you ask for the Enumerator, either explicitly by calling `GetEnumerator()`, or implicitly by calling `foreach`, or one of the non-deferred execution functions like `ToList()`, `ToDictionary()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Sum()`, the `Provider` will translate the expression into the format that the execution process understands and execute the query. Once the data is transported to the local process the enumerator is created.

Alas, sometimes you want to call your own functions in your query. SQL does not know these functions, and thus the Provider can't translate such `Expressions` into SQL. In fact, the provider of DbContext does not even know all Linq functions. See [supported and unsupported Linq methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

That is the moment when you use `AsEnumerable()`. If you ask for the Enumerator (in your `foreach` for example), the Provider will translate the Expression until `AsEnumerable`; send it to the execution process and transport all data to local process. After that, the query will be `AsEnumerable`: the rest of the LINQ will be performed in local memory, and thus your local functions can be called.

You could of course use ToList() to fetch all data to local memory and continue your linq after that. But that would be a waste if you'd only want the first element, or every other one.

This brings me to the final remark: the transport of the data from the DBMS to your local memory is one of the slower parts. Try to limit this transport to only the data you'll actually use.

For example: if you have a one-to-many relation between a Teacher and his Students, don't fetch the Teacher and his Students, because you'll transport `Student.TeacherId` many times, and they will all have the same value as `Teacher.Id`. Instead, only select the data you really want to use

Comment: I have little to add other than to emphasize that the query is executed when it is first enumerated, which happens explicitly when you add `.AsEnumerable()`. Before that point, the query is a LINQ-to-Entities or LINQ-to-SQL expression, manipulated by the Provider; after that point, the query becomes a LINQ-to-Objects expression that you can manipulate in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Not all `Select` projections, `Where` predicates, and `Aggregations` can be translated from C# Expressions into native database queries - in your case, the full LINQ expression attempts to construct a `AutoCompleteData` class with using  a custom function `BuildAutoCompleteText` to set one of its properties - this cannot be trivially converted into native database code like SQL.

In your case, `AsEnumerable` serves to terminate the work which will be done in SQL before this will be executed in SQL.

i.e.

```
.Include("ProductSubcategory")
.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
           && p.DiscontinuedDate == null)
```

will be executed in SQL, roughly as a `JOIN` to `ProductSubcategory`, and a `WHERE` predicate translated from your `Products` such as:

```
Product.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%' AND Product.DiscontinuedDate IS NULL
```

All work subsequent to the `AsEnumerable` (i.e. the projection of the results to  `AutoCompleteData` objects) will be done in-memory with LINQ  to objects.

`ToArray` and `ToList` will both execute (materialize) the result, but into different data structures. In your example, neither materialisation is required - since the return type is `IEnumerable<AutoCompleteData>` - the caller of the function might execute `.Any()` or `First()` which would render full materialisation wasteful - I would recommend you remove `.ToArray()` altogether - since the `using` statement controls the SQL lifespan is protected by the `AsEnumerable()` materialization, there is no issue with connection lifespans here.

Comment: thanks for reply. you said-- "In your case, AsEnumerable serves to terminate the work which will be done in SQL before this will be executed in SQL.  " this is not clear to me. please elaborate.

Comment: are you trying to say they use `AsEnumerable` because there is custom function `BuildAutoCompleteText`

Comment: You might want to read up about how Entity Framework *actually* works - it is able to translate LINQ Expression trees into raw SQL queries (if it couldn't, think about it - your code would have to load up the entire table into memory in order to manipulate it). However, such magic has limitations - only a subset of Common manipulations can be translated. The rest you'll need to do in good old fashioned code. 99% of the time you'll want to ensure that the WHERE clause predicates are executed natively in SQL. Others like SELECTs and GROUPings / Sum aggregations won't be too bad to do in memory.

Answer (score 1):

> tell me the intention of usage of .AsEnumerable() here in below query?

In this particular example `AsEnumerable()` was used to bring the data back to the client, because EF has no idea how to map `BuildAutoCompleteText()` to SQL query.

> they could use select directly.....is not it?

No, unless you define custom function `BuildAutoCompleteText` on SQL Server and make EF aware of that function.

> why they use .ToArray(); instead of Tolist() ?

In this case it does not matter both implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: you said-- In this particular example `AsEnumerable()` was used to bring the data back to the client, because EF has no idea how to map BuildAutoCompleteText() to SQL query.
ToList also bring the data back to the client. tell me what would happen if i do not use AsEnumerable() 
look like tell me what would happen ?

Comment: @koryakinp sure will & let u know.